# How to display number of lines textarea javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I´m trying to create a list with the number of lines of a textarea  like in a text editor. I have done it with a VBox item and adding TextField ListCell but when I scroll in the textarea, the VBox doesn´t  it . How can I do it?. This is part of code:

```
TextArea areaNueva = new TextArea();
areas.add(numeroTab, areaNueva);
areas.get(numeroTab).setStyle("-fx-font:15pt \"Times New Roman\";" + "-fx-focus-color:             transparent;");
BorderPane bor = new BorderPane();
ObservableList<TextFieldListCell> tf = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
TextFieldListCell cell = new TextFieldListCell();
VBox b = new VBox();
cell.setPrefSize(20,1);
cell.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman",11.35));
cell.setText("1");
tf.add(0,cell);
b.getChildren().addAll(tf);
b.setSpacing(-2);
b.setPadding(new Insets(3,0,0,0));
bor.setLeft(b);
bor.setCenter(areaNueva);
Tab tabNuevo = new Tab("Sin Titulo");
tabs.add(numeroTab, tabNuevo);
tabs.get(numeroTab).setClosable(true);
tabs.get(numeroTab).setContent(bor);
```

An with this I add new number of lines:

```
private ArrayList<ObservableList<TextFieldListCell>> lineas = new   ArrayList<ObservableList<TextFieldListCell>>();
String parte = null;
int i = 1;
while ((parte = br.readLine()) != null) {
      areaAUtilizar.appendText(parte + "\n");
      if(i!=1){
        TextFieldListCell c = new TextFieldListCell();
        c.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        c.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman",11.35));
        c.setPrefSize(20, 13);
        lineas.get(a).add(i-1,c);
        boxes.get(a).getChildren().setAll(lineas.get(a));
      }
      i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by removing the scroll of the textarea and the listview and put its opacity to 0, and putting both in a borderpane. After I put a scrollbar and the borderpane in a scrollpane. And for it to appear the scrollbar of the scrollpane I increased the height of the textarea and the listview when the lines of the textarea are more great than the prefheight.

Comment: Surely, but it helped me in that moment